# Is it possible to use the appengine/datastore package on the GAE flex environment?

Tags: google-app-engine, go, google-cloud-datastore

There are two different datastore packages for Google App Engine:
[google.golang.org/appengine/datastore](https://godoc.org/google.golang.org/appengine/datastore) and [cloud.google.com/go/datastore](https://godoc.org/cloud.google.com/go/datastore).

[The documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/go/datastore/reference) for the appengine/datastore package uses the standard environment while [the documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/go/using-cloud-datastore) for the cloud package uses the flex environment.

I have a Go application which uses the appengine/datastore package on the standard GAE environment. If I want to migrate this application from the standard environment to the flex environment do I need to switch to the cloud.google.com/go/datastore package, or can I continue using the appengine/datastore package? If not, why not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to migrate to cloud.google.com/go/datastore.

From [Migrating Services from the Standard Environment to the Flexible Environment](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/go/migrating):

> The App Engine flexible environment does not provide the API libraries
>   present in the App Engine SDK. If you [decide to migrate your
>   application from the App Engine standard environment to the flexible
>   environment](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/go/flexible-for-standard-users), you must update your code to use services and APIs
>   that are available across all Google Cloud Platform environments.

And from [Cloud Datastore](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/go/migrating#datastore):

> You can access [Google Cloud Datastore](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs) from anywhere using the
>   Cloud Datastore API. Use the [Google Cloud client libraries](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/cloud-client-libraries) to
>   store and retrieve data from Cloud Datastore.
>
> The same Cloud Datastore data is available regardless of if you use
>   the App Engine libraries, the Google Cloud client libraries, or call
>   the API directly.
>
> At this time ORM libraries that available in the standard environment
>   such as [ndb](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/ndb/) and [Objectify](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/gettingstarted/using-datastore-objectify) are not supported outside of the
>   standard environment.
>
> For more information, see the following guide:
>
> - [Using Cloud Datastore](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/go/using-cloud-datastore)